# Onbackpressed with dialog and check box don't show again

Tags: checkbox, android-alertdialog, onbackpressed

When the user first opens the application and then presses the back button to exit the application, an alertdialog will appear to exit and provide a rating.

I want to add a checkbox so that when the user has ticked then the alertdialog doesn't reappear when pressing the back button.

I've tried it with this code no luck. Users cannot exit the application when they have checked the checkbox.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dailog_review, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        CheckBox mCheckBox = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        // this is set the view from XML inside AlertDialog
        alert.setView(alertLayout);

        alert.setNeutralButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //System.exit(1);
                HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
                }
            }
        });

        AlertDialog mDialog = alert.create();
        mDialog.show();
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    storeDialogStatus(true);
                }else{
                    storeDialogStatus(false);
                }
            }
        });

        if(getDialogStatus()){
            mDialog.hide();
        }else{
            mDialog.show();
        }
    }

    private void storeDialogStatus(boolean isChecked){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CheckItem", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putBoolean("item", isChecked);
        mEditor.apply();
    }

    private boolean getDialogStatus(){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CheckItem", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("item", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided,
if the user selected do not show again
your condition is handling this as hiding the dialog, which is not showing, so you need to trigger super backpress instead

```
if(getDialogStatus()){
    HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
}else{
    mDialog.show();
}
```